# Regular expression in spring boot and angular

Tags: angular, spring

I am working on a project and I need the regular expressions to validate some data.

Here is what I want to obtain:

A character string which only begins with a letter between A z, and which is at least two characters long and at most 80, which can contain digits from 0 to 9 inside the string or at the end, and spaces inside too but which does not contain special characters like:
#$%@^&+=£µ?=.*!

Example: this is the formats that i want to validate.
Amanda1 test9  or
Amanda 5       or
Amanda

Thanks for your contribution

Comment: for each of these ... Amanda1 test9 or Amanda 5 or Amanda ... what is the desired result? would they all pass validation? what would not pass?

Comment: 1. they all pass validation:
Amanda1 test9,
 Amanda 5,
Amanda

2. I do not want they pass validation :
[0-9]Amanda@#$%@^&+=£µ?=.*!
[0-9]Amanda
---------
Amanda is an example of a string that only contains alphabetical characters from a to Z or A to z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
/^[A-Za-z][\w\s\]]{1,79}/
```

Comment: Thank you Dharman with that I could manipulate to adapt to several rules.